# Unweighted Directed Graph - Java

Tags: java, graph, directed-graph

I am new to Java and im working on implementing an unweighted directed Graph. Each Node holds an id and an object data. I am not sure about my approach so I need some advice on how to continue. Here's what im working with:

```
public class adjNode {
    public String nodeId;
    public Object data;

    adjNode(String nodeId, Object data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.nodeId = nodeId;
    }
}

public class Graph {
    private Map<adjNode, List<adjNode>> map = new HashMap<>();

    adjNode findNode(String nodeId) {
        adjNode temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) {
            temp = (adjNode) map.get(i);
            if (temp.nodeId == nodeId) {
                return temp;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void addNode(String name, Object data) {
        adjNode newNode = new adjNode(name, data);
        map.put(newNode, new LinkedList<>());
    }


    @Override
    public Object getData(String nodeId) throws InvalidNodeException {
        adjNode found = findNode(nodeId);
        if (found != null) {
            return found.data;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidNodeException(nodeId);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void setData(String nodeId, Object data) throws InvalidNodeException {
        adjNode found = findNode(nodeId);
        if (found != null) {
            found.data = data;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidNodeException(nodeId);
        }
    }
}
```

Does that make sense? Also how can I add directed edges and find incoming and outgoing neighbors?
Appreciate any help!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/What_is_JavaScript

Comment: There are quite a few basic tutorials on creating directed graph representations in Java. See e.g. here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-graphs
As a side-note, if you ever need graph data structures and algorithms, I'd recommend having a look at the [JGraphT project](https://jgrapht.org/)

Comment: Some feedback: not a bad first attempt. (1) you want to look into [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html). (2) Can you think of a way to significantly simplify and improve the `findNode(String nodeId)` method, for instance by using an extra `Map<String,AdjNode>` map?

Comment: Thank you for the link tutorial! I've visited many websites but never came across this one. It's a great explanation.